# Cannot profile a build with stack LTS 19.2 (GHC 9.0.2)

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am trying to build a profilable executable with `stack build --profile`. `stack build`, `stack test`, and `stack ghci` all work correctly. ([Full repo](https://github.com/xaviershay/plants) for reference)

I get many errors like the following:

```
StateVar                     >     Could not find module ‘Prelude’                                                                                                                                                                   
StateVar                     >     Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘base-4.15.1.0’?                                                                                                                
StateVar                     >     Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.                                                                                                                            
StateVar                     >    |                                                                                                                                                                                                  
StateVar                     > 72 | module Data.StateVar
```

This kind of makes sense to me - I'm using the GHC installed by stack, and when installing it didn't give me any indication that it was using profiling libraries.

```
> stack exec -- which ghc
/home/xavier/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.0.2/bin/ghc
```

I'm using `lts-19.2`.

Problems with this command seem to be relatively common in other questions, but usually the response is "stop using system GHC". Things I have tried that haven't worked:

- Reading the stack docs for `setup`, but found no reference to profiling.
- Reading the stack docs for `--profile`, but finding no reference to system profiling libraries.
- `stack clean`
- `rm -Rf ~/.stack/programs`
- `sudo apt install ghc-prof` and then `stack build --system-ghc --profile` (on a lark ... would prefer to stick to stack managed GHC...)

Comment: This is probably due to a packaging error in the GHC 9.0.2 release: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/21190#note_420026.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to sjakobi in the comments, this issue is most likely caused by a packaging error in GHC 9.0.2 (and 9.2.2 by the looks of it).

Downgrading to `lts-18.28` (GHC 8.10.7) fixed the issue and allowed me to profile.